# Continuous data discretization rules

Tags: modeling, continuous-data, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I know it all depends on the data, but I am looking for a general, most common rules for continuous data discretization.

For example It could be a list like this:
Use Supervised MDL discretization (e.g. Fayyad & Irani MDL), if this fails (i.e. no cuts could be found) Use Unsupervised equal frequency discretization, set number of bins based on the number of classes etc.

Again, I am aware that there is no gold standard, just looking for a starting point and most common practice in machine learning.

Comment: Why do you want to discretize?

Comment: I would like to campare two RoughSet based methods, which work on symbolic data only